# How can I make my game fall when off the platform I made?

Tags: java, gravity

I want it so when my player goes off the platform, (in checkCollision() method PlatformerPanel class) it will fall and then do something when gone off the screen, i haven't set up an end game screen yet but that's what I'm planning to do. Anyway, the problem is that it goes way too fast for some reason and falls too early, and also when an arrow key is pressed while its falling it will go back up to the platform.

Please try to help me overcome this or think of a new, easy to understand, way to do this/make this work the way i am planning.

EDIT 1:
I fixed the thing where it falls too early so don't worry about that

````
```
public class PlatformerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlatformerGameFrame platformerGame = new PlatformerGameFrame();
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PlatformerGameFrame extends JFrame{
    
    PlatformerGamePanel panel;
    
    PlatformerGameFrame() {
        panel = new PlatformerGamePanel();
        this.add(panel);
        this.setTitle("Platformer Game");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    }
}
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PlatformerGamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    PlatformerPlayer player1;
    PlatformerMap map1;
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int PLAYER_WIDTH = 50;
    static final int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 60;
    static final Dimension SCREEN_SIZE = new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    static boolean falling = false;
    Image backgroundImage;
    Thread gameThread;
    Image image;
    Graphics graphics;
    PlatformerMap map;
    
    public PlatformerGamePanel() {
        java.net.URL imgIcon = Main.class.getResource(
                "/Resources/spaceImage.jpg");
        backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(imgIcon).getImage();
        newPlayer();
        newMap();
        
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                player1.KeyPressed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                player1.KeyReleased(e);
            }
            
        });
        this.setPreferredSize(SCREEN_SIZE);
        this.setOpaque(true);
        
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
        
        
        
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        image = createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());
        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        draw(graphics);
        g.drawImage(image, 0,0, null);
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0,0, null);
        player1.paint(g);
        map.paint(g);
    }
    
    public void newPlayer() {
        player1 = new PlatformerPlayer((SCREEN_WIDTH/2)-(PLAYER_WIDTH/2), (SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)-(PLAYER_WIDTH/2), PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
    }
    
    public void newMap() {
        map = new PlatformerMap();
    }
    
    public void checkCollision() {
        if(player1.x > SCREEN_WIDTH-PLAYER_WIDTH) {
            player1.x = SCREEN_WIDTH-PLAYER_WIDTH;
        }
        else if(player1.x < 0) {
            player1.x = 0;
        }
        if(!(player1.x >map.PLATFORM_WIDTH)) {
            if(player1.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT-250) {
                player1.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT-250;
            }
        } else if(player1.x > map.PLATFORM_WIDTH) {
            gravity();
        }
    }
    public void falling() {
        
    }
    public void gravity() {
        player1.gravity();
    }
    
    public void move() {
        player1.move();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 120.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        while(true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime)/ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1) {
                move();
                checkCollision();
                gravity();
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
        
}
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PlatformerPlayer extends Rectangle {
    
    /*static int playerPosX = 100;
    static int playerPosY = 100;*/
    static double velocityY = 0;
    static double velocityX = 0;
    static int vertical_position;  
    static final int TERMINAL_VELOCITY = 200;
    static final int PLAYER_WIDTH = 50;
    static final int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 50;
    static int speed = 2;
    protected boolean falling = true;
    protected boolean jumping = false;
    double gravity = 0.05;
    
    public PlatformerPlayer(int x, int y, int PLAYERWIDTH, int PLAYERHEIGHT) {
        super(x,y,PLAYERWIDTH,PLAYERHEIGHT);
    }
    
    
    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            setXDirection(-speed);
            move();
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            setXDirection(speed);
            move();
        }
    }
    public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            setXDirection(0);
            move();
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            setXDirection(0);
            move();
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setColor(Color.red);
        g2D.fillRect(x, y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
    }

    
    public void setYDirection(int YDirection) {
        velocityY = YDirection;
    }
    public void setXDirection(int XDirection) {
        if(speed > 10) {
            speed = 10;
        }
        velocityX = XDirection;
    }
    public void move() {
        y += velocityY;
        x += velocityX;
    }
    public void gravity() {
        velocityY += gravity;
        if (velocityY > TERMINAL_VELOCITY)
        {
            velocityY = TERMINAL_VELOCITY;
        }
        vertical_position -= velocityY;
    }

    
}
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PlatformerMap extends Rectangle {
    int PLATFORM_WIDTH = 600;
    int PLATFORM_HEIGHT = 150;
    public PlatformerMap() {
        
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setColor(Color.gray);
        g2D.fillRect(100,400,PLATFORM_WIDTH,PLATFORM_HEIGHT);
    }
}
````

Comment: It's hard to give an exact answer without reading and fully understanding all your code (and I don't have the time to do that) so let me give a few hints instead: 1) try to step through your code with a debugger to check why the player falls too early (set a breakpoint at the code that initiates the fall), 2) once the player is falling, disable/ignore any key input that you don't want,

Comment: 3) if your player falls to fast, check your gravity calculation: `velocityY += gravity;` seems wrong as the time component is missing (there's a difference between adding 0.05 to velocity every 10ms or every ms etc.). You only update the game state once per tick but note that `delta` can be > 1 so any movement should take that into account for smooth animation. 4) Note that you're basically calling `gravity()` twice if the player falls: 1x in  `checkCollision();` and then again directly in your main loop.

Comment: Thank you for doing the best you can while not actually looking at my code, i will take what you've siad into consideration but im still looking for an answer where someojne can actually look at my code and come up with suggestions.